# Understanding the child process of a threaded GHC haskell program

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc, child-process

I'm trying to understand how the parent and various child OS threads work in a haskell program compiled with GHC `-threaded`.

Using

```
module Main where
import Control.Concurrent
main = do
    threadDelay 9999999999
```

Compiling with `-threaded` on ghc 8.6.5, and running with `+RTS -N3` for instance,  I can see

```
$ pstree -p 6615 
hello(6615)─┬─{ghc_ticker}(6618)
            ├─{hello:w}(6616)
            ├─{hello:w}(6617)
            ├─{hello:w}(6619)
            ├─{hello:w}(6620)
            ├─{hello:w}(6621)
            ├─{hello:w}(6622)
            └─{hello:w}(6623)
```

It looks like I get `N*2 + 1` of these "hello:w" threads as I vary `+RTS -N`.

**What are these "hello:w" threads, and why are there apparently two per HEC + 1?**

**And what does `ghc_ticker` do?**

I also noticed on a large real service I'm testing with `+RTS -N4` I'm getting e.g. 14 of these "my-service:w" threads, and when under load these process IDs seem to churn (half of them stay alive until I kill the service).

**Why 14, and why are half of them spawned and die?**

I'd also accept an answer that helped guide me to instrumenting my code to figure out these latter two questions.

Comment: Pretty sure those are the thread pool for `safe` ffi calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ghc_ticker` in [spawned](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/6aaa0655a721605740f23e49c5b4bf6165bfe865/rts/posix/itimer/Pthread.c#L167) at startup, it runs [this function](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/1c2c2d3dfd4c36884b22163872feb87122b4528d/rts/Timer.c#L42). It's purpose is described as

> The interval timer is used for profiling and for context switching in
>   the threaded build.

The other `*:w` threads are workers, they are [created](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/64ef4d7fb131f04769c6cab331af335bd87103ec/rts/Task.c#L497) whenever there is more work to do (aka [Task](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/c2290596f10ce732be85503d3ef0f0b50b7e925a/rts/Task.h#L19)), but there are no more spare workers, see [here](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/7f72b540288bbdb32a6750dd64b9d366501ed10c/rts/Capability.c#L569)

On startup ghc creates one worker per capability, then they are created as needed and reused when possible. It's hard to say why you have 14 workers in `-N4` case. I can only guess that they are serving IO manager threads: see [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Event.Thread.html#ensureIOManagerIsRunning). Let's not forget about FFI also - FFI call may block worker. You can try to put a breakpoint in `createOSThread` to see why workers are created.

You can read more about scheduler [here](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/rts/scheduler)

ADDED:
Hmm, I think I can explain the `N*2+1` workers: `N` workers per capability are created at startup; `N` more - IO manager event loops, one per capability; plus one IO manager timer thread. Though I'm not sure why the first `N` workers (created at startup) where not reused for IO manager threads.

Comment: The IO manager event loop blocks on a file descriptor. That's why they must run on their own thread.